# Unable to close store neostore.nodestore.db

Tags: neo4j

I've got a problem starting my Neo4J 2.0.0-M05 embedded instance with an empty graph.db folder.

If i try to do I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\workspace_VM\c13shh042\dist\neo4j-M05\data\graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:323)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:197)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
    at DE.data_experts.profi.util.vwkprotokoll.monitor.ejb.impl.GraphDatabaseManagerImpl.create(GraphDatabaseManagerImpl.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79)
    ... 172 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@b29807e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:504)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:300)
    ... 187 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@71e7579e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:504)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:165)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
    ... 189 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.UnderlyingStorageException: Unable to close store D:\workspace_VM\c13shh042\dist\neo4j-M05\data\graph.db\neostore.nodestore.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.close(CommonAbstractStore.java:603)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.createNodeStore(StoreFactory.java:263)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.createNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:225)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.createNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:219)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.ensureStoreExists(StoreFactory.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:282)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
    ... 192 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Der Vorgang ist bei einer Datei mit einem geöffneten Bereich, der einem Benutzer zugeordnet ist, nicht anwendbar
>> in english: The process is in a file with an open area that is associated with a user, not applicable
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.truncate0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.truncate(FileDispatcherImpl.java:92)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.truncate(FileChannelImpl.java:346)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.close(CommonAbstractStore.java:583)
    ... 198 more
```

I'm using Windows 7 as host system and Java 1.7.40. I checked if there is a process locking the graph.db folder or whatever, but like Process Explorer says, everything is fine.

Yesterday i was able to start the embedded database and fill it with my migration script, but i used Neo4J 2.0.0M-04 at this time.

Is this probably a bug in the latest release or what can i do to avoid it?

Best regards;
Marcus

Comment: I tried switching back to Neo4J 2.0.0M-04 and it worked perfectly. So this seems to be a bug in the latest milestone release.

Comment: I am also getting this error on latest milestone